# Adding a sort column into list C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, dictionary

I built a `List <MyObject>` which has an object collection in a specific order but in this list I want to manage a kind of SORT column but created by myself.

I mean, for example I want to enumerate manually 10 objects; 2 the first 7 ones sequentially from 1 to 7 and the last 3 ones from 8 to 10 multiply by -1 so at the end I'll have my list

```
List[0] {1, obj1}
List[1] {2, obj2}
List[2] {3, obj3}
List[3] {4, obj4}
List[4] {5, obj5}
List[5] {6, obj6}
List[6] {7, obj7}
List[7] {-8, obj8}
List[8] {-9, obj9}
List[9] {-10, obj10}
```

Then finally I could sort it (ascending) and I'll have `-10, -9, -8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

Is there a way to do this avoiding so many loops and do it with `linq` (I hope) and what type the list can I use?

**EDIT**

What I am trying to do is to collect object to be saved in db but they need to go in a sequence (FK) but if I recognize that 3 of them are gonna be deleted they must be in proper order to avoid FK conflicts. So I thought that it was the best thing to do. Suggestions?

Comment: can you show what you already tried doing?

Comment: if you create your list manually like you said, you can then sort it using a custom comparison. In the custom comparison you can use any property of the elements that you want. Check this method out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can use the conveniently named [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on your list:

```
var list = new List<MyType>() { ... };
list.Sort((x, y) => x.Prop1.CompareTo(y.Prop1));
```

Or if this is not actually a `List<T>` but some other type of `IEnumerable<T>`, use Linq's [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method instead:

```
var unordered = ...
var ordered = unordered.OrderBy(x => x.Prop1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in Lync as an example:

```
void Main()
{
    // Create the list
    var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                          .Select (index => new Holder {
                                               Name = "Info " + index,
                                               SortOrder = index
                                               }
                                  )
                          .ToList();

    //set sort order
    items.Skip(7)
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(itm => itm.SortOrder = itm.SortOrder * -1);

    // Now sort
    var sorted = items.OrderBy (itm => itm.SortOrder);

    sorted.Dump();

/* Output
Name SortOrder
Info 10 -10
Info 9 -9
Info 8 -8
Info 1 1
Info 2 2
Info 3 3
Info 4 4
Info 5 5
Info 6 6
Info 7 7
*/
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Holder
{
    public string Name   { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your number column positive at all when you are sorting.

If you want to use LINQ extensions methods, use OrderBy like this:

```
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(i => Math.Abs(i.Number));
```